Unable to Connect to Internet After Upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.4
On Thursday, My OS updated to 22.04.4, and the nightmare began.
Everything worked fine until Friday morning when even the network settings on my PC disappeared. I received the "NetworkManager not active" error, so after one day and a half of following all the troubleshooting suggested in this form and downloading thousands of .deb files from the archives, I managed to get back my connection icons and settings, and the pc seems to be connected, both with wifi and ethernet, but it doesn't reach internet connection. I've also manually updated the kernel, as someone suggested, but still no internet. Attached is a screenshot of the situation.
screenshot of my sad sad terminal and network settings
I'm a newyby to the Ubuntu world, so be patient if I'm missing something obvious, but please help. I don't know what to do anymore, and my work deadlines are so behind I want to cry.
EDIT
I've changed the language settings in english to more clarity when posting screenshots and codes. Here's another screenshot of my current situation, but in english.
Also, for completeness of the information, here's all that come to mind can be useful:
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BenderKetiofender"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz
Access Point: B0:A7:B9:DA:F2:1C
Bit Rate=234 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-30 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:77   Missed beacon:0

nmcli general
STATE                  CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
connected (site only)  limited       enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 

lshw -c network
*-network:0               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlp0s20f3
   version: 20
   serial: 2c:6d:c1:aa:11:03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-35-generic firmware=77.2df8986f.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.u ip=192.168.1.117 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6053194000-6053197fff
`*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 20
   serial: b4:45:06:4c:73:93
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.5.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=192.168.1.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:150 memory:a2300000-a231ffff'

lspci -knn | grep -A 2 -i net
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:4070]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-LM [8086:15fb] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (13) I219-LM [1028:0a21]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e

nmcli
enp0s31f6: connected to Connessione via cavo 1
    "Intel I219-LM"
    ethernet (e1000e), B4:45:06:4C:73:93, hw, mtu 1500
    ip4 default
    inet4 192.168.1.113/24
    route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 100
    route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 20100
wlp0s20f3: connected to BenderKetiofender
    "Intel 6 AX201"
    wifi (iwlwifi), 2C:6D:C1:AA:11:03, hw, mtu 1500
    inet4 192.168.1.117/24
    route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 600
    route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 20600
p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3: disconnected
    "p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3"
wifi-p2p, hw
lo: unmanaged
    "lo"
loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
DNS configuration:
servers: 192.168.1.1
interface: wlp0s20f3
servers: 192.168.1.1
interface: enp0s31f6

nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         B4:45:06:4C:73:93
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Connessione via cavo 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveC>
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.113/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt =>
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp0s20f3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         2C:6D:C1:AA:11:03
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     BenderKetiofender
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveC>
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.117/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt =>
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256

nmcli connection show
NAME                    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE >
Connessione via cavo 1  4cba5758-9e86-3b4c-9ac0-17bb9bbc81e5  ethernet  enp0s31>
BenderKetiofender       80f620b0-a34d-438d-94ac-e1585760285d  wifi      wlp0s20>
DipinfoWPA              f9af2330-9240-47cb-908b-1528fcef475c  wifi      --     >
DipinfoWPA1             d4ab8249-108f-4f51-ae37-9d774f81888e  wifi      --     >
Jarvis                  47f9ffef-aeb3-4431-b78a-e52ba9ef2366  wifi      --     >


Welcome to AskUbuntu! What is the kernel you have installed? Output of uname -r.

Hi! Thank you for answering! The kernel is 6.5.0-35-generic, I just updated it manually, installing all the packages via usb

Hi, I'm sorry, i don't think I understood the question. The toggle button for the wifi connection is on, even if I'm also connected with the ethernet cable just to test both, the only off thing I see is the plane mode.
Anyway, with WiFi turned on nothing happened, the wifi is indicated as "Connected" but I can't navigate. Same for ethernet, the pc recongnise it as its connected, but can't navigate (or most importantly call apt-get commands in terminal).
I've also tried to disable the IPv6, because I found it worked for someone else, but the issue still remains.

Does this answer your question? Intel AX201 Wi-Fi 6 and Ethernet Won't Work Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10
